# How to create temp tables + unions in Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

This is working perfectly in Mssql.

How to rewrite this in Oracle:

```
create table #temptable (mgr bigint)
insert into #temptable (mgr)  ( 
select 1 
union select 2
union select 3)
```

Comment: What do you want to reach? Do you know that the data in a temp table is preserved only till the session ends or if there is commit/rollback (it depends on the type of temporary table)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a temporary table like this:

```
create global temporary table temptable (mgr number);
```

To insert data into this table:

```
insert into temptable
select 1 from dual union all
select 2 from dual union all
select 3 from dual;
```